# Update / replace multiple values MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have the following data in MongoDB

```
{
  "BOOK_ID": "100",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 1",
  "BOOK_DESC": "abcd",
  "BOOK_AUTH": "150"
},
{
  "BOOK_ID": "101",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 2",
  "BOOK_DESC": "efgh",
  "BOOK_AUTH": "150"
},
{
  "BOOK_ID": "102",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 3",
  "BOOK_DESC": "ijkl",
  "BOOK_AUTH": "150"
},
{
  "BOOK_ID": "103",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 13",
  "BOOK_DESC": "ijklss",
  "BOOK_AUTH": "151"
}
```

I have a requirement to replace few book names to new names respectively for a particular author, and is as follows:

```
author_id = 150
changes = [
  {'old_name': 'Book 1', 'new_name': 'Book 11'},
  {'old_name': 'Book 2', 'new_name': 'Book 22'}
]
```

I tried to change for one book name, but it doesnt work. The query I tried is as follows:

```
db.Books.update({
  "BOOK_AUTH": "150"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "$replaceOne": {
        "input": "$BOOK_NAME",
        "find": "Book 1",
        "replacement": "Book 11"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

How to replace multiple items, the following is the expected output:

```
{
  "BOOK_ID": "100",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 11",
  "BOOK_DESC": "abcd",
  "BOOK_AUTH": "150"
},
{
  "BOOK_ID": "101",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 22",
  "BOOK_DESC": "efgh",
  "BOOK_AUTH": "150"
},
{
  "BOOK_ID": "102",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 3",
  "BOOK_DESC": "ijkl",
  "BOOK_AUTH": "150"
},
{
  "BOOK_ID": "103",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 13",
  "BOOK_DESC": "ijklss",
  "BOOK_AUTH": "151"
}
```

Kindly help with replacing multiple values. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$replaceOne`, you can simply try this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "BOOK_AUTH": "150",
  "BOOK_NAME": {
    $in: [
      "Book 1",
      "Book 2"
    ]
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      BOOK_NAME: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$BOOK_NAME",
              "Book 1"
            ]
          },
          then: "Book 11",
          else: "Book 22"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jeGNqcuGINr)

For more than two books, use this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "BOOK_AUTH": "150",
  "BOOK_NAME": {
    $in: [
      "Book 1",
      "Book 2"
    ]
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      BOOK_NAME: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  "$BOOK_NAME",
                  "Book 1"
                ]
              },
              then: "Book 11"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  "$BOOK_NAME",
                  "Book 2"
                ]
              },
              then: "Book 22"
            }
          ],
          default: "$BOOK_NAME"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Playground link - 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kl3Zf5yzQzF)

Comment: what if there are more than two books to be replaced?

Comment: You can use `$switch`, and add the more names in the `$in` array.

Comment: could you please help in updating your answer

Comment: Done @Jeril. Added a new query.